# Remove Class when current toggle is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

The title is a bit of a tongue twister. A brief description of the fiddle, is that it's a toggle style accordion where the toggle state changes color when one of the divs is toggled. I've got it working to where if **another** div is toggled it will close that previous div and open the new div while changing the toggle state.

The issue I am running into is if a user wants to close the current toggle without clicking a different div it will close the current toggle but not change the toggle state back to it's original state. I am currently using `this` and have tried multiple things including if the container `'is: visible'` or `hasClass` then to remove the toggle class, but nothing seems to work. I've also tried a different `slideToggle` function, but of course that applied it to the toggled element I've found.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/NFTFw/1256/

**What I am trying to do?**

I want the current toggle class to change back to its original state if the user clicks the **current** toggled div **or** clicks another div. So essentially I want the user to have either option.

CODE:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.column').each(function (index) {
          $(this).delay(750 * index).fadeIn(1500);
      });
      $('.column').hide();
      $('.body').hide();
      $('.column').each(function () {
          var $toggle = $(this);
          $('.toggle', $toggle).click(function () {
              $(".toggle").removeClass("toggle-d");
              $(this).addClass('toggle-d');
              $body = $('.body', $toggle);
              $body.slideToggle();
              $('.body').not($body).hide();
          });
      });
  });
```

Comment: Nothing happens in the fiddle when I click any of the elements.

Comment: Oops, had it set to only run if the window is 600px or less, I've updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if the thing that you're clicking already has the class. If so, remove it, if not, add it. I suspect the problem you were having with `hasClass()` is that you were attempting to check the wrong `this`.

Oooh I did a bad thing and didn't remove the class when a new div was clicked. I've fixed that and updated the jsfiddle

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpercy/NFTFw/1255/)

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('.column').each(function (index) {
          $(this).delay(750 * index).fadeIn(1500);
      });
      $('.column').hide();
      var width = $(window).width();
      if (width <= 600) {   
      $('.body').hide();
      $('.column').each(function () {
          var $toggle = $(this);
          $('.toggle', $toggle).click(function () {
              if($(this).hasClass('toggle-d')){
                $(this).removeClass("toggle-d");
              }
              else{
                $('.toggle').removeClass('toggle-d');
                $(this).addClass('toggle-d');
              }
              $body = $('.body', $toggle);
              $body.slideToggle();
              $('.body').not($body).hide();
          });
      });
      }
  });
```

Comment: Ah, so I was checking the wrong $this then. Well, thank you. Answer accepted.

Comment: Yeah, I'd assume you were checking the `.column` not the actual toggle.

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest is to pass the element itself in the function

in the index.html Do this

```
<a class = 'classname' onclick = toggle(this)>
   Your Content Here
</a>
```

After that in the script.js

what i am saying is in javascript, i believe you can easily convert it to jquery

```
function toggle(value){
    if(value.className == 'the predefined value'){
        value.className = value.className + ' Your new class addition'
        // remember there should be a space if you are adding an additional class to the present class, else directly change the classname
    }
    else{
        value.className = 'the predefined value'        
}}
```

this will toggle your classname whenever the element is clicked